# PHP AJAX JSON send to modal window

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, modal-dialog

I'm getting better using the Ajax method.  I keep running into small issues though.

For instance, I am trying to create a display-comment type feature, where when the user clicks on a link, a modal window will open with a history of the comments for a partner-code.

I've already used PHP to return data into a grid.  I don't think I need to display the code I used to return the data.

Here is the ECHO I'm using to store data-attributes and other information in a HYPERLINK:

```
 <?php
   ......

   echo "<td><a href='' id='pComment' name='".$row[partner_code]."' 
                class='comment' data-toggle='modal' data-code='".$row[partner_code']."' 
                data-name='".$row[partner_name]."'>" . $row[partner_name] . "</a></td>";
```

As you can see, I tried to store the ROW data [partner_code] in the NAME attribute.  I also have a data-attribute called data-code that also contains $row[partner_code].

In my javascript file, called global.js, here is what I have so far:

```
 $('a#pComment').on('click', function()
 {
   var partnercode = $('a').attr('data-code');
   alert(partnercode);
 }
```

I have the php code that will retrieve the partnercode and run the query.  That works fine, but it's the javascript code above I am having problems with.

Currently, when I click the link, I am trying to alert the partner-code.  But the only thing I am receiving is this:

[image]

I tried this:

```
 var partnercode = $('a#pComment').attr('data-code');
```

But the alert box will show 0000000001 for every single link that I click.

I know once I can get the window to at least show the correct partner-code, I can then send it over to my PHP file to run the query to retrieve the comments.  But I cannot get past this.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like a `view source` to see if that data-code attribute actually gets a value assigned? perhaps you've got MULTIPLE cells with the same ID, and the FIRST one in the html doesn't have a value to begin with.

Comment: @Marc B - I checked Chrome's console.  The name attribute and the data-code attribute both show the same code for each link. All of the attributes look good and all have values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant have dupliacte ids, so change that to a class:

```
echo "<td><a href='' name='".$row[partner_code]."' 
            class='comment pComment' data-toggle='modal' data-code='".$row[partner_code']."'
            data-name='".$row[partner_name]."'>" . $row[partner_name] . "</a></td>";
```

Then target the clicked link in you js with `this`

```
$('a.pComment').on('click', function()
 {
   var partnercode = $(this).attr('data-code');
   alert(partnercode);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, sir.  This is what I was looking for.  I am successfully able to alert the partnercode.  Now, I just have to get it over to my query page.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First time answering someone other than myself.

Why are you not using `$(this)` instead? Also, why are you referencing to $('a') again while you've already got the element that fired the event? Selecting `$('a')` would mean you're selecting all of them, right?

Also jQuery has the data method for you to use. You can check here: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Idk, see if any of this helps.

```
 $('a#pComment').on('click', function()
 {
   var partnercode = $(this).data('code');
   console.log(partnercode);
 }
```

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I saw my error and have corrected it.

Comment: Ah, didn't see your comment on the previous answer. Good luck!